# copy OSX file with permissions

Tags: macos, permissions, installation, copy, driver

I have an OSX FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext file for an FTDI Chipset Driver where the Info.plist file has been modified for optimum performance.

I would like to supply the modified file to users of our hardware, so that it can be copied to:  MacHD/System/Library/Extensions/ and it must have "system" ownership and permissions.

What would be the easiest way to:

1. Copy the working FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext file (package) retaining the current ownership and priveleges for distribution ?
2. Provide the user with "simple" terminal instructions on how to copy and overwrite the file to MacHD/System/Library/Extensions/ with system ownership and permissions ?

Every time I try and test, the permissions and ownership get set to the current user so the driver will not load at startup.

It would be optimal if I could bundle this as a simple installer, so the user could just double click to install.

Thanks

Peter

Edit: Needs to work on 10.6.8 and above. I am aware of a finder option in OS X 10.8 that allows for "duplicate exactly" and "paste exactly", but this is not an option for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `cp -p`

> -p    Cause cp to preserve the following attributes of each source
>   file in the copy: modification time, access time, file flags, file
>   mode, user
>              ID, and group ID, as allowed by permissions.  Access Control Lists (ACLs) and Extended Attributes (EAs), including resource
>   forks, will
>              also be preserved.

Comment: The .ktext package is considered a directory and is not copied using cp -p

Comment: Powermac:~ kyle$ cp -r /System/Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext /Users/Kyle/Desktop/tmp/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext
cp: /System/Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext is a directory (not copied).

Comment: cp -p -r /System/Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext /Users/Kyle/Desktop/tmp/

Comment: Note that a kext and its containing files should be owned by root:wheel, so if you use sudo to copy it, then that ownership will be used and you don't need the -p

Answer (score 0):

We are using a script to alter the FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext file: See: https://github.com/arminbw/wiretouch/blob/master/perl/modify-ftdi-driver-settings.pl

However, did you by any chance experience problems after upgrading to 10.10? See: [Patched FTDIUSBSerialDriver kext has to be unloaded/reloaded after reboot (OSX 10.10). Any ideas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798032/patched-ftdiusbserialdriver-kext-has-to-be-unloaded-reloaded-after-reboot-osx-1)